# API polling and timeout

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, reactive-programming, polling

I have a polling use-case where:

1. I want to call an API that, based on business logic, returns numbers(1-10) or error (network issue/ exception in API etc..) instantly (1.5-2 sec).
2. If the API returns an error (network issue/ exception in API etc..) then I want to unsubscribe the polling and display error.
3. If the API returns success, I want to check the return value and un-subscribe(if the return value is 5) or keep the polling going.
4. I want to call API every 5 sec.
5. I want to keep the max time(timeout/threshold) for the polling as 3mins. If I don't get the desired response(number 5) in these 3mins, the polling should error out.

This is how I have implemented it currently:

```
this.trackSpoke$ = interval(5000)
                .pipe(
                    timeout(250000),
                    startWith(0),
                    switchMap(() =>
                        this.sharedService.pollForAPropertyValue(
                            "newuser"
                        )
                    )
                )
                .subscribe(
                    (data: SpokeProperty) => {
                        this.CheckSpokeStatus(data);
                    },
                    error => {
                        this.trackSpoke$.unsubscribe();
                        this.createSpokeState.CdhResponseTimedOut();
                    }
                );


private CheckSpokeStatus(data) {
        if (data.PropertyValue === "5") {
            this.trackSpoke$.unsubscribe();
            //display success   
        } else {
              //keep the polling going
        }
    }
```

But, the above implementation is not timing out.

What needs to be done so that it times out and I am able to achieve all mentioned use-case?

Comment: `interval(5000)` emits every 5s so the timeout right after that will never throw an error because it's receiving a value every 5s

Comment: Got you. Now how do I timeout?

Comment: Whenever I see polling and API ... I have to ask, have you considered using a message queue?

Answer (score 5):

First of all using `interval` for API polling is quite an anti-pattern because `interval` won't "wait" for your http request to finish - potentially triggering multiple requests (if the request takes more then 5s to complete).

I prefer to use [`defer`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-defer) with [`repeatWhen`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-repeatWhen) and `delay` (see the code below).

The `timeout` is not triggering because the `interval` is ticking every 5s preventing the timeout from ever occurring. The `defer`/`repeatWhen` combo should also fix that.

Instead of manually unsubscribing consider using [`takeWhile`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-takeWhile) to unsubscribe the Observable for you.

Also using `this.trackSpoke$.unsubscribe();` in the error handler is not needed because Observable is unsubscribed automatically in case of an error.

```
this.trackSpoke$ = defer(() => this.sharedService.pollForAPropertyValue("newuser"))
    .pipe(
        timeout(250000),
        repeatWhen(notifications => notifications.delay(5000)),
        takeWhile(data => this.CheckSpokeStatus(data)),
    )
    .subscribe(
        error => {
            this.createSpokeState.CdhResponseTimedOut();
        }
    );


private CheckSpokeStatus(data) {
    return data.PropertyValue !== "5";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a pretty similar use case.

written with rxjs 7.8.1

```
from(fakeDelayedRequest()).pipe(
  map((response) => {
    if (isValidResponse(response)) {
      return response;
    } else {
      throw `Not a valid response`;
    }
  }),
  retry({
    // getRetryDelayTimeOrThrow decides if we retry or not, depending on the error
    //  - returns an observable that triggers when the next request shall be sent
    //  - or throws the error which leads to exiting the retry loop
    delay: getRetryDelayTimeOrThrow,
  }),
  timeout({
    each: maxTimeout,
    with: () => throwError(() => 'TIMEOUT'),
  })
);

function getRetryDelayTimeOrThrow(e: any, retryCount: number) {
  console.error(e);

  if (repeatAfterError(e)) {
    return timer(getPollInterval(retryCount));
  } else {
    throw e;
  }
}
```

You can find the full working code [in this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-http-polling-qmjsxa?devtoolsheight=80&file=index.ts)